# How to get the error occurred in SQS source queue in DLQ

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

Is it possible to get the error occurred in the source queue when a message is moved to DLQ ? If yes, how can I get the error? There is some information in the header ?

[image]

I have a service that listener to messages from the source and DLQ queues. The Source queue is associated with DLQ and has a retry policy, 3 attempts are made to process the incoming message, but in case of failure the message is not removed from the queue. So if the maximum of 3 failed attempts is reached, the message is forwarded to the DLQ queue, when the message arrives at DLQ I would like to know what was the reason (failure, exception...) that occurred when the message was processed in the source queue. I did some tests here using localstack to simulate but apparently when the message arrives in the DLQ queue it is not possible to obtain the exception information that occurred.

Comment: It is not SQS that is generating the error, it is whatever code that is _consuming_ the message. Could you please explain your architecture? For example, what is consuming the messages in the SQS queue -- is it an AWS Lambda function?

Comment: Probably, you'll need to correlate the error message from the queue consumer with the message in the DLQ.  If you're not logging the message ID, it might be a little tricky to correlate.  If volumes are not high, time should work.

Answer (score 1):

The comments have it right, but here it is spelled out a little more.  For reference, read the [redrive policy section of the CreateQueue API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_CreateQueue.html).

A message is sent to the DLQ when its ReceiveCount exceeds the maxReceiveCount.
The ReceiveCount is incremented each time your consumer calls ReceiveMessage and receives the message.
When your consumer receives the message but then fails to call DeleteMessage before the [VisibilityTimeout](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-visibility-timeout.html), the message becomes available to be Received again in a subsequent ReceiveMessage call.

The point here is that SQS has no idea why your code did not call DeleteMessage, all it knows is that the message was received maxReceiveCount times without ever being deleted.

To understand the reasoning you will need to implement logging and look at your consumer logs.